# String and byte[] issue java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am converting a String to byte[] and then again byte[] to String in java using the `getbytes()` and String constructor,

```
String message = "Hello World";
byte[] message1 = message.getbytes();
```

using PipedInput/OutputStream I send this to another thread, where,

```
byte[] getit = new byte[1000];
pipedinputstream.read(getit);
print(new String(getit));
```

This last print result in 1000 to be printed... I want the actual string length. How can i do that?

Comment: what's the type of `pipedinputstream`?

Comment: @Shine: make an educated guess :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the String, you need to get the number of bytes read, and give the length to your String:

```
byte[] getit = new byte[1000];
int readed = pipedinputstream.read(getit);
print(new String(getit, 0, readed));
```

Note that if your String is longer than 1000 bytes, it will be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the number of bytes read. Do it as below:

```
  byte[] getit = new byte[1000]; 
  int bytesRead = pipedinputstream.read(getit); 
  print(new String(getit, 0, bytesRead).length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getText (byte[] arr)
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (arr.length);

for (byte b: arr)
    if (b != 32)
        sb.append ((char) b);

return sb.toString ();
}
```

not so clean, but should work.

Answer (score -1):

> I am converting a String to byte[] and then again byte[] to String

Why? The round trip is guaranteed not to work. String is not a container for binary data. Don't do this. Stop beating your head against the wall: the pain will stop after a while.

Comment: i want data to flow thru the pipedinputstream! it takes only byte[] as argument...

Comment: @VineetMenon So wrap InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter around them, then you can write chars. But my next question would be why you think you need pipes? I've never put a piped stream into production in 15 years.

Comment: :I want to exchange data(text) between 2 threads...synch. Anyways the problem is solved by Vivien's Solution..